# Add images to a table one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

can someone please advise how I can load images from an array (called preLoadArray) into table cells one by one. The table is 13 x 4 cells. 
The function is meant to increment the image ID and call back to itself to add them with a short setTimeout() to delay the process & make it animated. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

```
function showCard(){
//when button is clicked
document.writeln("<table>");
    for (m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
    document.writeln("<tr>");
    for (n = 0; n < 13; n++) {
        preLoadImages[n] = new Image();
        preLoadImages[n].src = n + '.gif'; 

        document.writeln("<td id=\"\"><img height=\"80\" id=\"" + preLoadImages[(m * 13) + n] + "\" \"></td>");
        }
        document.writeln("</tr>");
    }
    document.writeln("</table>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to preload images in any array if you are directly specifying their src..

Here is a code which will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script>
        function showCard() {

            var t = "<table><thead></thead><tbody>";
            for (m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
                t += "<tr>";
                for (n = 0; n < 4; n++) {              

                    t += "<td><img height=\"80\" width=\"80\" src=\"" +  ((m * 4) + n) + ".jpg\"/></td>";
                }
                t += "</tr>";
            }
            t += "</tbody></table>";

            document.getElementById("ll").innerHTML = t;
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="showCard();">
    <div id="ll"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank Victor. If i need to add this to an existing table, would i use doc append? Once i figure this out, then i need to apply the setTimeout to each image.

Comment: @BigSpudnuts Yes ! you can use doc `append` function or in this case use `addRow()` function to get the results and timer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in javascript `document.writeln()`, probably you meant to use `document.write()`. Yet this is not recommended to use. Better to go with `innerHTML` or `.appendChild`:

```js
function showCard() {
  var t = "<table>"
  for (m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
    t += "<tr>";
    for (n = 0; n < 13; n++) {
      preLoadImages[n] = new Image();
      preLoadImages[n].src = n + '.gif';

      t += "<td id=\"\"><img height=\"80\" id=\"" + preLoadImages[(m * 13) + n] + "\" \"></td>";
    }
    t += "</tr>";
  }
  t += "</table>";

  document.innerHTML = t;

}
```